# Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract graduate{
     uint studentId;
     string name;
     string major;
     uint totalGrade;

     function setGraduate(uint x, string y, string z, uint v) public{
           studentId = x;
           name = y;
           major = z;
           totalGrade = v;
     }

    function getGraduate() public view returns (uint _studentId,string _name,string _major,uint _totalGrade){
          return studentId;
          return name;
          return major;
          return totalGrade;
    }

}
```

> browser/graduate.sol:17:9: TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
>
> return studentId;
>
> ^--------------^

same on 4 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
return studentId;
return name;
return major;
return totalGrade;
```

To this:

```
return (studentId,
        name,
        major,
        totalGrade);
```

Comment: And BTW, what does `totalGrade - v;` suppose to do???

Comment: The problem has been resolved. Thank you.

Comment: And "totalGrade - v" is a typo.... thank you.